# Password Grant access token generation

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel Passport `password` grant type to enable my mobile clients(Android, iOS ...) to generate an access token. My mobile clients cannot use `oauth/token` route to get access and refresh tokens themselves, because it uses `web` middleware (as I understand). My questions is, 
Should I make request to `oauth/token` myself in server by passing data mobile clients posted? If I do this how do I bypass `web` middleware. (Manually creating a dummy user and using it to bypass web middleware is not that I want and weird solution)

Comment: Did you try changing the middleware to something like auth?

Comment: from doc - "The JSON API is guarded by the web and auth middleware; therefore, it may only be called from your own application. It is not able to be called from an external source."

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case I always this by removing `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class` from the `web` middlewareGroup on `app/Kernel.php`.
I'm also using [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) to allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing headers. My apps are API only and the clients are external (both mobile and web clients are external) and they all authenticate and renew tokens themselves interacting with the Passport routes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you sure that this is the formal way to do it?